# Questions on memory/storage in smart contract

Tags: solidity

I've recently finished a course in smart contract and am trying to expand on the current project. One thing I'm trying to do is give more info into each campaign - things like, description, category, etc. I've modified my smart contract, but am running into an error, if you can help me take a look and point me towards the right direction, that'd be really appreciated! Also, if you can just take a look overall how I've modified the contracts to see if I have any redundancy anywhere, that'd be awesome. Cheers.

the error i'm getting on line 50 is - `TypeError: Member "manager" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct Campaign.NewCampaignType storage ref[] storage ref
require(msg.sender == campaigns.manager);`

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract CampaignFactory {

struct NewCampaignType {
string description;
uint minimumContribution;
string campaignCategory;
string endDate;
address manager;
}

address[] public deployedCampaigns;

function createCampaign(string description, uint minimumContribution, string campaignCategory, string endDate) public {
address newlyCreatedCampaign = new Campaign(description, minimumContribution, campaignCategory, endDate, msg.sender);
deployedCampaigns.push(newlyCreatedCampaign);
}

function getDeployedCampaigns() public view returns (address[]) {
return deployedCampaigns;
}
}

contract Campaign {

struct NewCampaignType {
string description;
uint minimumContribution;
string campaignCategory;
string endDate;
address manager;
}

struct Request {
string description;
uint value;
address recipient;
bool complete;
uint approvalCount;
mapping(address => bool) approvals;
}

NewCampaignType[] public campaigns;
Request[] public requests;
mapping(address => bool) public approvers;
uint public approversCount;

modifier restricted() {
require(msg.sender == campaigns.manager);
_;
}

function Campaign(string description, uint minimumContribution, string campaignCategory, string endDate, address manager) public {
NewCampaignType memory createCampaign = NewCampaignType({
description: description,
minimumContribution: minimumContribution,
campaignCategory: campaignCategory,
endDate: endDate,
manager: manager
});
campaigns.push(createCampaign);
}

function contribute() public payable {
require(msg.value > campaigns.minimumContribution);

approvers[msg.sender] = true;
approversCount++;
}

function createRequest(string description, uint value, address recipient) public restricted {
Request memory newRequest = Request({
description: description,
value: value,
recipient: recipient,
complete: false,
approvalCount: 0
});

requests.push(newRequest);
}

function approveRequest(uint index) public {
Request storage request = requests[index];

require(approvers[msg.sender]);
require(!request.approvals[msg.sender]);

request.approvals[msg.sender] = true;
request.approvalCount++;
}

function finalizeRequest(uint index) public restricted {
Request storage request = requests[index];

require(request.approvalCount > (approversCount / 2));
require(!request.complete);

request.recipient.transfer(request.value);
request.complete = true;
}

function getSummary() public view returns (
uint, uint, uint, uint, address
) {
return (
campaigns.minimumContribution,
this.balance,
requests.length,
approversCount,
campaigns.manager
);
}

function getRequestsCount() public view returns (uint) {
return requests.length;
}
}
```

Comment: thanks ivicaa for the edit, sorry i'm relatively new to the whole thing, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`campaigns` is an array.

Like the error said, an array doesn't have a member called `manager`.

Comment: ah ok, so i would need access the array then the property of manager in the object? thanks

Comment: Yes. `campaigns[0].manager` would be valid, as long as you had inserted at least one element into the `campaigns` array.